# RewriteEngine question in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have put this in my htaccess

```
#Redirect all england visitor to this web page , england.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^222\.167\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^112\.111\. 
........
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxx.com/england.php  [R=302,L]
```

While non-england visitors will land in index.php

However, i have found that, england visitors can visit this website www.xxx.com/england.php if there type the address in address bar. 
How can make this page only available to england ip address?
thx

Comment: Why do you need such restriction? What if I'm from England but currently in France or Germany and still would like to access `/english.php` -- why forbidding me?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to know which IP addresses are in England.

You can get the data you require from something like http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry.  You can then look up the IP address and determine it's location.

I don't know if putting the data in the .htaccess will be a viable solution.

Quote from the maxmind site...

> Due to the large size of geolocation databases, we generally recommend
>   using our binary format with one of our APIs, since they are highly
>   optimized for speed and disk space. On the other hand, if you have a
>   requirement to import the data into a SQL database, the CSV format is
>   recommended. We have listed some guidelines for importing and querying
>   the data with a SQL database.

But I guess you can try it and see..

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use `mod_authz_host` and "deny for all" by default, then only allow the IP ranges you want to let in. Finally, add an ErrorPage that redirects forbidden visitors to the index page.

See [the Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html).